# What kind of participle clause is applied in the following examples?

Tags: participle-clauses, supplementation

1. > Going back to the subject of justin bieber, famous for rubbing everyone the wrong way, if he is waiting for Selena GomeZ, his ex-girlfriend, to provide him protection from the blows then he can talk to her hand or possibly kiss her bum.

   In the example above, does it stand for a participle clause about condition? I mean can it be reformed as "if we go back to the..." or about "simultaneous action"?
2. > Speaking of selena's bum,the internet is awash with images of her bare bum hanging out for all and sundry to public.

   In the example above, I also wonder about variety of participle clause in the sentence. And plus, what is the subject in the phrase "speaking of selena's bum"? I mean who is speaking about it?"

NOTE: The second example is the sentence that immediately follows the first example

Comment: These are conversational segues, referring back to an earlier context, and connecting that context to the sentence that is going to be spoken next. The second quote seems mangled, by the way.  "sundry to public". A verb is missing.

Comment: @TRomano That's a pretty good answer all by itself, and would be of value to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

**"Going back to"** and **"Speaking of"** are both [conversation segues](https://toughnickel.com/misc/How-to-Use-a-Segue-in-Public-Speaking) that are *introductory* in your examples.

Very many set phrases, words and idioms are used as segues in speech. They can be comparing words *(like, similarly, as compared to)*, linking words *(and, also, the same as)*, opposing words *(yet, but, in contrast, however, despite that)*, and set phrases *(Before we move on, Speaking of, As I mentioned before, Going back to)*.

A segue *(pronounced as seg-way)* is a smooth transition between two events, sequences, sentences, topics, and compositions.

> An introductory conversation segue is always followed by a comma. Mid-sentence segues are preceded by a comma and followed by a comma.